# How do I host a .net core application on IIS?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis

The application launches on Visual Studio using the IIS Express profile but I can't get it to run on the IIS local server.

When I try to host the application on the local IIS server, I cannot get it to work.
I ran into a few problems while doing this like Error 500.19, and Error 401.
Now, I have the directory listing displayed instead of the website.

Please Note - I am new to web programming and it's the first time I am trying to host using IIS server.
Since the website runs fine on VS IIS Express, I am guessing, some of the IIS Settings that I am using could be incorrect.

Comment: `I am guessing, some of the IIS Settings that I am using could be incorrect`. Then please add that information to your question.

Comment: There are quite a few configurations required before serving your application on IIS server. Sharing your config would help us to diagnose the main issue.

Comment: Which config files should I share? Where can I find them?

Comment: "Now, I have the directory listing displayed instead of the website" looks rather terrible that you are on the wrong path very far. Roll back all your changes to the very beginning please, and run a report to see what might be wrong, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ancm-diagnostics.html

Comment: Have you installed `.NET Core Hosting Bundle` on your hosting machine?

Comment: Yes, that is installed.

Comment: Alright, follow the steps accordingly from the given answer.

Comment: @Shilpa You may refer to this post https://windowswebhostingreview.com/simple-way-to-host-your-asp-net-core-in-iis/. If you already install .net core hosting bundle, you may follow that tutorial.

Answer (score 5):

> The application launches on Visual Studio using the IIS Express
> profile but I can't get it to run on the IIS local server.

Alright, first of all, Please check your control panel if you have enabled following features:

[image]

**Note:** As you are new, I would recommed you to enable all options in [Internet information service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/jj635847(v=ws.11)#to-open-iis-manager-from-the-start-screen) to avoid further issues because if you miss anything which will lead you to another trouble that would be difficult to assist.

Check your asp.net core runtime on your hosting machine

```
dotnet --list-sdks
```

[image]

Install prerequisite files for hosting

```
dotnet-hosting-7.0.3-win
```

**Note:** If you don't have [please download from here.](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/thank-you/runtime-aspnetcore-7.0.3-windows-hosting-bundle-installer)

Check if the modules installed accordingly:

[image]

You should have following module:

[image]

Add New Site By Right Click:

[image]

[image]

**Note:** Make sure, you have right to access the path and the port you would be entered is unused or no other application is using.

Configure App Pool:

[image]

[image]

**Note:** For asp.net core app please select No managed Code from the dropdown.

Run The App:

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

**Note:** If you would like to know more details on how to publish [ASP.NET Core app to IIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/publish-to-iis?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#prerequisites) you could [check our official document here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/publish-to-iis?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed steps. After following the above steps, I now have HTTP Error 500.30. I tried the following: Run the application from command prompt using dotnet command. It runs fine. The event logger has the following error:  System.InvalidOperationException: The Negotiate Authentication handler cannot be used on a server that directly supports Windows Authentication. Enable Windows Authentication for the server and the Negotiate Authentication handler will defer to it.

Comment: I turned on the Windows authentication and Anonymous authentication in the IIS server. The site is now not reachable. Not sure what's going on. No logs in the event logger this time.

Comment: Remove all of your previous configuration and then follow the steps accordingly what I showed, no more additional changes at the begining. Once it works as expected then start your customization. As I said earlier, for any additional settings if anything goes wrong it would be harder for you to fix. Also use a port other than 80. For instance, you can use port 8001.

Comment: Works for ASP.NET Core MVC as well as WebAPI.   Thanks!

Comment: Glad to know, it helped you.